# Looking for animals dataset for Deep Learning classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, image-classification, computer-vision

Do you know any datasets that contain animals and their accurate classifications? I am looking for any dataset that categorizes animals.

For example:

- a dataset with insects, with an image of an insect and its scientific name as label
- a dataset with dogs of different breeds, their scientific names and images.
- a dataset with Myriapodes (like centipedes or millipedes), images and their names as labels
- mammals
- birds
- reptiles
- ...

Generally, I am looking for **datasets of all animals** worldwide, classified as good as possible.

I would very much appreciate it!

Here a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_classes) of possible classes (superclasses, groups, etc.).

Comment: this question may be better suitted on [opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, a single dataset with ***all*** animals does not seem to exist (perhaps you can make one :D ), but there are plenty of datasets with a subset of animal species. Here are a few I can think of:

- There are *many* datasets on Kaggle. Searching for "[species](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=species+&sizeStart=90%2CMB)", "[animal](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=animal&sizeStart=90%2CMB)", or some other smarter keyword should give some options. I found the [10 Monkey Species](https://www.kaggle.com/slothkong/10-monkey-species), [STL-10](https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/stl10), [bird species classification](https://www.kaggle.com/akash2907/bird-species-classification), and [Animals-10](https://www.kaggle.com/alessiocorrado99/animals10) datasets fairly quickly, for example.
- Most large-scale datasets like [OpenImages](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html), [CIFAR](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/), the [Visual Genome](http://visualgenome.org/), and [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#home) have animals as some of the categories (among non-animal ones).
- The [iNaturalist](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06642) dataset is a large scale species classification dataset (see the [2018](https://sites.google.com/view/fgvc5/competitions/inaturalist) and [2019](https://www.kaggle.com/c/inaturalist-2019-fgvc6) competitions as well).
- [The Nature Conservancy Fisheries Monitoring dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-nature-conservancy-fisheries-monitoring/overview) focuses on fish identification.
- The [Caltech-UCSD Birds-200-2011](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/visipedia/CUB-200-2011.html) is a standard dataset of birds.
- The [animals with attributes 2 dataset](https://cvml.ist.ac.at/AwA2/) focuses on zero-shot learning (also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00600)).
- The [Snapshot Serengeti](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201526) dataset covers 40 mammals from the African Savannah.
- The [Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/pets/) is good for fine-grained cat and dog classification.
- [A survey on image-based insect classification](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01441203/document) by Martineau et al has references to a number of image datasets for insect identification (though I am not sure how many are public).
- The group at the [Labeled Information Library of Alexandria: Biology and Conservation (LILA BC)](http://lila.science/) track a large set of animal conservation and ecology datasets, including many involving image-based species recognition [here](http://lila.science/datasets).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Kaggle [competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification) for a dataset on DOG breed.